# Overflow not for every element

Tags: html, css

is there a way to make `overflow:hidden` which wouldn't be applied for every child?

Little example:

```
<div class="parent" style="overflow:hidden; position: relative;">
   ...
   <div class="hidden" style="top: -50px"> AA </div> <!-- overflowed and hidden -->
   <div class="visible" style="bottom: -50px"> BB </div> <!-- overflowed and visible -->
   ... 
</div>
```

**I need to have 1 element, which will be visible even if it is overflowing.**

Comment: I would start by asking, why do you need the overflow in this case on the parent?

Comment: Are you wanting the children to overflow their parent? It's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your visible element can be `position: absolute` it will ignore the `overflow: hidden` of its parent. Here's a snippet example.

Please notice your parent should be contained inside another div with `position: relative` to properly work.

```css
.visible{
  position: absolute;
}
.parent{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.relative{
  position: relative;
}

/* presentational styles */
.parent{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.hidden{
  background: yellow;
}
.visible{
  background: red;
}
.parent,
.hidden,
.visible{
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="hidden" style="top: -50px"> AA </div> <!-- overflowed and hidden -->
     <div class="visible" style="bottom: -50px"> BB </div> <!-- overflowed and visible -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.hidden-flow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="parent hidden-flow" style=" position: relative;">
   ...
   <div class="hidden hidden-flow" style="top: -50px"> AA </div> <!-- overflowed and hidden -->
   <div class="visible" style="bottom: -50px"> BB </div> <!-- overflowed and visible -->
   ... 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be difficult without adding more elements. The only way I can think of is by adding another container with the same position as the parent. But this will break you elements flow, unless you use absolute positioning. It would be something along these lines:

```
<style>
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.subparent{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

.parent > div {
  position: absolute;
}

.visible {
}

.hidden {

}
</style>

<div class="parent">
   ...
   <div class="subparent">
     <div class="hidden" style="top: -50px"> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </div> <!-- overflowed and hidden -->

   </div>

   <div class="visible" style="bottom: -50px"> BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB </div> <!-- overflowed and visible -->
   ... 
</div>
```

The element that should be hidden if they overflow should be in the div with class subparent.